# Is it possible to do something like conditional branching during Integration Test?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-integration-test

I would like to change the checks during an IntegrationTest in Flutter between an error thrown and a normal case, but I don't know how to do it.
Is there a way to do this in IntegrationTest, like a conditional branch?